# C recursion code

Tags: c, function, recursion, return-value

I need help with understanding this code using recursion.

```
    int power(int n1,int n2);
    int main()
    {
        int base, exp;
        printf("Enter base number: ");
        scanf("%d",&base);
        printf("Enter power number(positive integer): ");
        scanf("%d",&exp);
        printf("%d^%d = %d", base, exp, power(base, exp));
        return 0;
   }
   int power(int base,int exp)
   {
       if ( exp!=1 )
       return (base*power(base,exp-1));
   }
```

The code works fine but I don't understand why it still manages to return a value when `exp` is 1 even when the condition in the function body evaluates to false, so I think it shouldn't return anything then.

For example, if the function is called in the `main()` function and I assign the values of `5` and `1` to `base` and `exp` respectively, I expect that I shouldn't get a return value because `exp` is `1` and my function returns something only if `exp !=1` and also, there is no `else` part in the function body to cover the case when `exp` is `1`. 
I know about C returning garbage values when the return value is not specified but in this case, it returns the right answer and I tested it several times. For example, when I call it in the main function with `base=7` and `exp=1`, it returns `7` as my answer and even with other "base" values, it always returns the base which is the right answer. And that exactly is my source of confusion - How is C managing to return the right answer to me when the IF clause of the function body evaluates to false...
I guess I'm missing something here.

Comment: Your code invokes Undefined Behavior as you don't return an `int` when `exp` is 1. The function will return a "random" , "garbage" value from memory. So anything can be the result.

Comment: It does not return when exp = 1, but if you catch the return value when call the function, it will be junk value from memory

Comment: I know about C  returning garbage values when the return value is not specified but in this case, it returns the right answer and I tested it several times. For example, when I call it in the main function with base = 7 and exp =1, it returns 7 as my answer and even with other "base" values, it always returns the base which is the right answer. And that exactly is my source of confusion - How is C managing to return the right answer to me when the IF clause of the function body evaluates to false...

Answer (score 3):

Actually your function is [Undefined Behaviour](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), because of is not returning nothing in case of `exp == 1`

The value you have in return to your main function is something random.

Answer (score 1):

You may warned by the compiler in the declaration `int power(int base,int exp)`

> No return, in function returning non-void

Hence, you will get [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), when you call `power()` with `exp = 1`.

**Note that:** Your `power()` will fall into *recursion trap* if `exp` is negative.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, for `exp` having value  `1`, there is no `return` statement. If the return value of that call is used in the caller function, program shows UB.<sup>See note below</sup>

That said, the issue will also hold true in case you're calling `power()` with `exp` value something other than `1`, as `power()` will end up calling itself with `exp` as `1` at some point of time.

Finally, `exp`  being an `int`, it can accept a negative value and go into infinite loop, only to create stack overflow by infinite recursion.

---

Note: As per the `C11` standard, if the function is terminated by reaching the closing `}` and the returned value is used, it invokes invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Ref: Chapter `§6.9.1`, paragraph 12,

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: I know about C returning garbage values when the return value is not specified but in this case, it returns the right answer and I tested it several times. For example, when I call it in the main function with base = 7 and exp =1, it returns 7 as my answer and even with other "base" values, it always returns the base which is the right answer. And that exactly is my source of confusion - How is C managing to return the right answer to me when the IF clause of the function body evaluates to false...

Comment: @AyorindeKomolafe well, undefined behaviour is undefined. It includes working "as expected" case also.

Comment: really? I didn't know that. I thought if it was undefined, it might throw different answers to me each time I run it, but it was giving me consistently right answers.